# How to return back stackoverflow chat mobile view to desktop on same window ?

Tags: support, chat

I am recently created a new chat section called **jQuery Fans**. When I am enter into my chat room there is a log and some links of Stackoverflow on right bottom of window. There is a link for mobile site.[image]

When I am click on it my chat room becomes **responsive** and looks like [image]

But Now I ca't find any links to return back **desktop view** on same page. How can I return back to desktop view on same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, click on `Menu` then click on `Full site`:

[image]

Comment: I am having a similar problem on my Kindle,  I changed my veiw but now I cant find the menu button to change it back.